# JQuery and JqGrid retrieve data from row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

How I can retrieve data from jqgrid row, if I have only the number of the row?

For example, what do I have to do if I want the id column of the 3rd row?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can get the data by row id. So you can do following:

```
var index = 2; // zero-based index of row so it means the 3rd row
var rowId = jQuery('#list tr:eq('+index+')').attr('id');
```

(here I suppose that the `<table>` element of your jqGrid has id="list"). After you know the id of the row you can get the row data with respect of [getRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method or the data from one cell only with respect of [getCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method:

```
var dataFromTheRow = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getRowData', rowId);
var dataFromCellByColumnIndex = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getCell', rowId, 7);
var dataFromCellByColumnName = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getCell', rowId, 'Tax');
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, be carefull with methods **getCell** and **getRowData** if case you are editing the row or cell.
"This will return the cell content and not the actuall value of the input element."